# concatenate two variables in bash

Tags: bash, concatenation

I wanted to concatenate two variables, but it seems that there is some overwriting.

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMBER1=$(seq 1 900 | sort -R | head -1)
FIRST=$(sed -n ''$NUMBER1'p' names.txt)
echo ${FIRST}
echo "${FIRST}${NUMBER1}"
```

Where names.txt is a list of names.
For example when I run this code, I get the output as,

> Gregoria
>
> 159goria

Notice $FIRST was partially overwritten by $NUMBER1 .

The correct output should have been,

> Gregoria
>
> Gregoria159

can someone please help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Your input file has CR+LF line endings.  Run `dos2unix` or some other utility to remove CRs.  For example, `dos2unix names.txt` might help.

Comment: please show us `names.txt` content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `names.txt` file has Windows line-endings, CR-LF. The CR (carriage return) is not being recognized as part of the new-line sequence by `sed`, so it stays on the end of the line `Gregoria<CR>`; consequently, the next characters get overprinted at the beginning of the line.

Use `dos2unix` or some equivalent to fix the line endings.

Comment: What you change are the line-endings. How you change them, if you have `dos2unix` installed, is `dos2unix names.txt`. For a lot of elaboration, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: alternative to dos2unix: `sed -i 's/\r$//' filename`